# Cannot build project when targeting device in xcode

Tags: xcode6.1

I'm using Xcode 6.1 and I get the error `Security/SecAccessControl.h file not found`
plus some other errors you can see in the image here. (this is a swift project). The same happens with Objective C projects (just add 10 errors)

[image: Xcode 6.1 errors]

These errors occur only when I target my real device, and not when I target the simulator. I have iOS 8.1 installed on the device.

Deployment is set to 8.1

This happens to all projects even new empty projects.

This seems to be a bug in Xcode 6.1 but I'm not sure.

Any fixes/workarounds or preferences I need to know about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalling Xcode solved this issue